# Blocking traffic to one of the docker service tasks (containers)

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, docker-swarm, iptables, network-partitioning

There are 3 distinct vms where *RabbitMQ* service is deployed in *global mode*.
My goal is to block traffic to one of the *RabbitMQ* service containers. 
Tried using iptables to [Reproduce RabbitMQ network partition scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795308/reproduce-rabbitmq-network-partition-scenario)

by adding iptables chain

`iptables -A DOCKER-INGRESS -d 10.255.0.33 -p tcp --dport amqp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j DROP`

on 2 docker nodes where *RabbitMQ* service task containers run.
 *10.255.0.33* is ip of the container from  swarm overlay network taken from `docker service inspect` output.
Though, traffic still passes through and network partition is not reproduced.
How to block traffic to service container correctly?

Comment: Is it possible (in your case) to have the three distinct VMs on different networks?

Comment: yes, it's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to block traffic from/to container identified by container_id

Steps 2-3 should run inside the container.

1) Enter the container:

```
docker exec -it --privileged --env http_proxy=proxy_ip container_id bash
```

`--env http_proxy=proxy_ip` is not needed if you can connect to web directly and not behind some (corporate) proxy

2) This step assumes that the underlying image OS is  *Debian*  based. If it's RED-HAT based, use the  *yum*  package installer equivalent commands. If it's some other OS family, use the appropriate package installer commands.

Install  *iptables*

```
apt-get update &amp;&amp; apt-get install -y iptables
```

3) Block traffic to/from container whose virtual ip is 10.0.0.183

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.183 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -d 10.0.0.183 -j DROP
```