# How to produce RabbitMQ network partition in Windows

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I would like to reproduce the RabbitMQ network partition in Windows 10 machines. I have found one solution at [Reproduce RabbitMQ network partition scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795308/reproduce-rabbitmq-network-partition-scenario) but it is not in Windows.

I have tried the following but unable to reproduce the scenario:

1. stopped one cluster node by the command `rabbitmqctl stop_app` for a few minutes.
2. blocked port **25672** in the firewall both Inbound rules and Outbound rules for a few minutes.

Is there any other way that I should try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally produce the network partition by disabling ethernet for a few minutes in one of the cluster node and then again enable it.

[image]